# Transactional Replication guidance

Tags: sql-server, replication, azure-sql-database

As a real newcomer to Transactional Replication I would appreciate some guidance.

I have a production database on premise and the need to take two tables from here and copy them regularly to a SQL Azure database. This is so that our suppliers can run a very simple label printing program from their premises so they can stick labels on the goods they supply to us.

We raise a Purchase Order in house on our ERP system and send it to our supplier. They produce the goods and print the labels. Stick the labels on the goods and send them to us.

That is it. Nothing fancy in the way of filters or otherwise (This can all be handled by the program).

Is this a fairly easy thing to set up? Is there an idiots guide anywhere that could show me how to go about this?

Comment: How frequent you need to move the data from on-prem to azure ? How big are the tables - rowcount & Size ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways  by which you can transfer data and all depends on this part of question..

> copy them regularly to a SQL Azure database

1.If you want once a day,you can write ssis package and do the logic of checking/merging data in that

2.You also can write C# program which does this for two tables and run this through SQLServer agent..

3.if you are looking for near realtime data transfer,i would go with Transactional replication.[This is supported now](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/transactional-replication-to-azure-sql-db/)..

Setting up is very easy task and same as Onpremises ,but with one exception of no pull subsribers .

This [article from Joe Sack](http://sqlmag.com/database-backup-and-recovery/getting-started-transactional-replication) will help you on how to set up..

There are also some limitations which you need to account for..

The publisher and distributor must be at least at one of the following versions:

```
SQL Server 2016

SQL Server 2014 SP1 CU3

SQL Server 2014 RTM CU10

SQL Server 2012 SP2 CU8
```

You can read this link [for more details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt589530.aspx)..